# Couchbase replication issue with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, couchbase

I'm having an issue with my Elasticsearch replication of my Couchbase DB.

Certain documents in my DB are not being replicated correctly. Rather than replicating as full couchbase documents, there is an entry with _type of couchbaseCheckpoint pointing to certain documents. These checkpoints never seem to update or grab the documents correctly, even after a refresh. This seems to occur at random, with some documents replicating correctly and being stored as full couchbaseDocuments, while others stay as these checkpoints. I'm not seeing any errors related to this in my logs at all.

versions:

couchbase 3.0.1
elasticsearch 1.3
couchbase elasticsearch plugin 2.0.0

`{
   "name":"xxx",
   "age": "1",
 }`

Comment: Couchbase has not release version 3.0.1 yet. 3.0 was release this week.

Comment: in my couchbase console its shown as-
You are running version 3.0.1 Enterprise Edition (build-1323).

Comment: also in couchbase 2.5 version the problem comes..

Comment: I have some doubt regarding the key value storage in couchbase. Normally we store data as document. I have some questions.
1. What is the difference between document type and key-value type?
2. How can i achieve key - value storage ? Can you explain with a small example.
3. what is the benefit of storing as key-value?